# How to assign two different type variable to one variable in c++

Tags: c++

I wrote a program that uses a normal Serial port and a Bluetooth Serial Port to send logs to UART and Bluetooth respectively

```
HardwareSerial Serial;
BluetoothSerial SerialBT;
```

for example when i want to send something with them i write this

```
Serial.println("Hello World"); //prints Hello world in normal Serial port
SerialBT.println("Hello World"); // prints Hello World in Bluetooth serial
```

i defined some preprocessors that checks whether Bluetooth or Normal Serial port is active and if one of them is active print in the active one

my problem is here that i want to declare a variable like "Debugger" that i can assign it with "SerialBT" or "Serial" to write something like this

somewere in my init function

```
#if BLUETOOTHDEBUG
Debugger=&SerialBT;
#else
Debugger=&Serial;
#endif
```

and in code

```
Debbugger->println("Hello World")
```

instead of using if in whole code

Comment: Do these have a common base-class? Could they have one? If so it's easy. If not the answer is basically "no".

Comment: You can always design a wrapper class to expose them in a common interface.

Comment: [HardwareSerial](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/master/cores/esp8266/HardwareSerial.h) and [BluetoothSerial](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/blob/master/libraries/BluetoothSerial/src/BluetoothSerial.h) both seem derived from [Stream](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/master/cores/esp8266/Stream.h), so perhaps `Stream &Debugger` should work just fine?

Comment: @tadman yeah these two class are derived from the same class

Comment: Then if that's a pointer it'll be pretty easy to assign. C++ shouldn't complain.

Comment: @orhtej2 you are right they are both derived from Stream i compiled Stream *Debugger and it sent error

Comment: BluetoothSerial.cpp.o:(.bss.client+0x0): multiple definition of `client

Comment: include the full error and relevant code in your question

Comment: Create a [mcve], because that sounds like you messed up something unrelated. If `class B` and `class C` both inherit from `class A`, then `A *a = new B()` _will_ work; likewise, if you have `B b`, then `A *a = &b` will as well.

Comment: @ Nic Hartley you are totally right. i wrote a minimal program and it worked thanks to all especially you and orhtej2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based on Comments and the fact that HardwareSerial and BluetoothSerial class are both derived from Stream class, I added

```
Stream *Debugger
```

and it worked